# Is there an odd continuous map $f:S^{2}\to GL(2,\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Motivated by [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182953/non-invertibility-of-certain-integral-arising-from-group-action)
 and as  an attempt to a possible generalization of the Borsuk Ulam type theorems we ask:

> Is there  an odd continuous map $f:S^{2}\to GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ (Or  $GL(2n, \mathbb{C})$?

Comment: By odd do you mean something like $f(-x) = f(x)^{-1}$?

Comment: @JohnMa  No  I  mean $f(-x)=-f(x)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the following answers this in the affirmative.

Let us identify $S^3$ with the obvious subset of $\Bbb{C}^2$:
$$
S^3=\{(z_1,z_2)\mid |z_1|^2+|z_2|^2=1\}.
$$
We can then identify $S^3$ with $SU(2)\subset GL_2(\Bbb{C})$ by the embedding
$$
f:S^3\to SU(2),\ (z_1,z_2)\mapsto
\left(\begin{array}{rr}z_1&z_2\\-z_2^*&z_1^*\end{array}\right).
$$
Restricting $f$ to your favorite copy of $S^2$ inside $S^3$ then gives a mapping of the desired type. Complex conjugation commutes with negation, so the resulting mapping is odd.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting answer. This implies that there is no  an odd continuos map from $GL(2n, \mathbb{C})$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$